# Errors installing plyr / rcpp

Tags: r, plyr, rcpp

I have two computers and in one of them I can't manage to install the plyr package for R.
This is the error I get:

```
* installing *source* package ‘plyr’ ...
** package ‘plyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -pipe -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
RcppExports.cpp: En la función ‘SEXPREC* plyr_loop_apply(SEXP, SEXP)’:
RcppExports.cpp:15:9: error: ‘input_parameter’ no es un miembro de ‘Rcpp::traits’
RcppExports.cpp:15:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
RcppExports.cpp:15:40: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
RcppExports.cpp:16:9: error: ‘input_parameter’ no es un miembro de ‘Rcpp::traits’
RcppExports.cpp:16:49: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
RcppExports.cpp:16:50: error: ‘::type’ no se ha declarado
RcppExports.cpp:16:57: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘f’
RcppExports.cpp:17:36: error: ‘n’ no se declaró en este ámbito
RcppExports.cpp:17:39: error: ‘f’ no se declaró en este ámbito
RcppExports.cpp: En la función ‘SEXPREC* plyr_split_indices(SEXP, SEXP)’:
RcppExports.cpp:31:9: error: ‘input_parameter’ no es un miembro de ‘Rcpp::traits’
RcppExports.cpp:31:54: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
RcppExports.cpp:31:55: error: ‘::type’ no se ha declarado
RcppExports.cpp:31:62: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘group’
RcppExports.cpp:32:9: error: ‘input_parameter’ no es un miembro de ‘Rcpp::traits’
RcppExports.cpp:32:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
RcppExports.cpp:32:40: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
RcppExports.cpp:33:65: error: ‘group’ no se declaró en este ámbito
RcppExports.cpp:33:72: error: ‘n’ no se declaró en este ámbito
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘plyr’
* removing ‘/home/rgalhama/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/plyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plyr’ had non-zero exit status
```

It looks like the package can't be compiled, but I can't figure out why.
Before the installation starts, I get this warning message:

> Warning in install.packages :   dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available

I have installed rcpp from the system (as sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpp), since I don't find a way to install it from R:

> install.packages("Rcpp", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org') Installing package(s) into
>   ‘/home/rgalhama/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   package ‘Rcpp’ is not
>   available (for R version 2.15.2)

But still I don't know if these errors are related.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Got it!

The solution in my case was:

First, update R:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu quantal/' >>  /etc/apt/sources.list" 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

Then install codetools package from R:

```
install.packages("codetools")
```

After this, the installation of `plyr` went smoothly.

Comment: You second step makes no sense. The codetools package is already part of the r-base package.  But glad to hear you have it working now.

Comment: It complained about not finding it and it worked after I installed it. Maybe it's not part of the base package anymore, no idea.

Comment: It should get pulled in as a depends.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an old version:

> R version 2.15.2

You can always try to update R to the most recent version.

Comment: Ooops, I didn't notice! I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Just for future reference, I add the code to update R:
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu quantal/' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev

Comment: Still it looks like updating R is not enough. I manage to install Rcpp but I still get exactly the same error when installing plyr :(

Comment: Good that you found the README to update your R. Now make sure you only have one version of Rcpp installed -- so make sure you removed the `r-cran-rcpp` from your (old) Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem. Installing the Debian/Ubuntu `build-essential` package solved the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

As it turns out, it's hard for R to compile things if a compiler isn't installed.

Answer (score 2):

After having a similar issue myself when trying to install plyr in RStudio on Ubuntu I found the following solution:

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-plyr
```

Just dropping it here to help prevent people from going down quite a rabbit hole, like I did, before finding a working solution.